# How do the effects from multiple Tiamats stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

Let's say I buy 3 Tiamats. How does that 50% (or 35% ranged) AoE damage stack?

Will minion/champions near my main target get 150% (or 105% ranged) damage?

Comment: @Brant sorry, but why did you edit my question? with 50%(35%) and 150%(105%) I meant 50% melee or 35% ranged / 150% melee or 105% ranged

Comment: My mistake. I was trying to clarify the question, but I misunderstood what you were asking (and how Tiamat works). Sorry about that, and thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The damage stacks additively, so with 3 Tiamats you will be dealing 150% AOE damage. Meaning you are dealing MORE damage to surrounding targets than to your initial target.

For your amusement, here is a video of caitlyn stacking 3 Tiamats. You can see the surrounding champions take 216(ish) damage 3 times, once for each Tiamat.

Answer (score 5):

Tiamats will stack additively, meaning each Tiamat will deal 50% splash for melee attacks or 35% splash for ranged attacks. With 6 Tiamats, you can do an extra 300% splash damage with melee and/or 210% extra splash damage with ranged attacks. The radius of this splash damage is fairly small (185, only slightly larger than the range of Singed's Fling attack).

The splash damage does not confer additional benefits, such as life steal or chance to critical hit, although bonus damage if the original hit was a critical will still transfer into the % based damage.

Do note that the splash only applies to default attacks or attacks that proc on-next-hit effects such as Ezreal's Mystic Shot, Warwick's Infinite Duress, Gangplank's Parrrley, or Fiora's Blade Waltz.

Tiamat is generally considered underpowered due to the fact that it's overall benefit is very minor compared to the cost effectiveness of what you could be getting for a similar price. Additionally, it is the only item in the game that builds directly out of 4 basic items, making it one of the hardest items to plan for in regards to inventory management.

Answer (score 4):

The LoL Wiki says:

- The splash damage passive from the item is not unique, meaning that it is possible to obtain up to 300% splash damage with 6  Tiamats.
- The bonus splash damage of each  Tiamat is dealt separately.

The answer is, yes you would be dealing 150% of your damage to sourrounding units/champions. But, the cost of the item is pretty high for what it is worth, and if you are building 3 tiamats your damage won't even be that high...You might as well just build one and beef up your base damage. Also unless you are playing with total noobs, your enemies won't be bunched up enough for you to really get more than 2 chamions in one splash.

Comment: 5 Tiamats makes for some pretty gnarly Gangplank Parrrlays, especially if you increase your crit with item #6.

Comment: This has been fixed and no longer works only one timat effects now so the other two are just stats(Same with sunfire cape stacking)

Comment: If people are still stacking them on Fiora who came out last patch I don't think it was fixed. I just went through all of the patch notes for tiamat and nothing says they made the passive UNIQUE.

Comment: @Cem22lp This is wrong. The stacking still works on Tiamats but not on Sunfire. The difference is the UNIQUE keyword in the description.

Comment: @StrixVaria hmm thought i read that they had fixed it so it didn't stack with itself that's good to know then thank you

Answer (score 0):

To be asking whether passives stack or not, you should just look at the description of the item

If the item shows an **unique** passive e.g. those from **Trinity Force**, these passives will not stack BUT all the other stats  outside the unique passive will

Other items with stackable passives with are **Bloodthirster** bonus attack, **Warmogs** bonus health, **Archangels staff** bonus ability power passive, ... Altough it's better to choose different items instead of stacking one and the same.

Comment: Dont forget, the **UNIQUE** stacks work only for the same item. eg: Philosopher's stone "UNIQUE Passive: Gain an additional 5 Gold every 10 seconds." and Heart of Gold "UNIQUE Passive: Gain an additional 5 Gold every 10 seconds." still stack (03-08-2012) but 2x Philosopher's stone don't

Comment: ADDING: Sometimes certain items will be noted in the unique passive lane e.g. Trinity Force unique passive of bonus damage (based on AD) does not stack with Sheen or Lich Bane